# Import Angular Module in separate express project in same workspace

Tags: angular, express, es6-modules

Is it possible to import an Angular Module into an express server which are technically different projects, but are in the same workspace?

Background is, that Angular Universal exports an MainServerModule which has to be imported into the main express file like that

```
import {AppServerModule} from "./ui/src/main.server";
...
    app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
}));
```

Both, the Angular project and the express project are ESM. When trying to run that code, it gives the following error

```
CustomError: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\xxx\WebstormProjects\xxx\src\ui\src\main.server' imported from C:\Users\xxx\WebstormProjects\xxx\src\app.ts
```

The thing is, that in the Angular Universal sample app, they have both (express and angular) running in the same project. I would like to avoid that, as i want to have the backend and frontend separated.

Comment: The path `./ui/src/main.server` seems to be interpreted relative to `C:\Users\xxx\WebstormProjects\xxx\src`, which is your express project, I assume. Can you give an absolute path to the angular project instead?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to [set up a multi-project workspace](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#multiple-projects).
You will basically have a single `angular.json` file that defines a workspace or root project, in which then you will have the child projects.

Next, you can define one of the child projects, the one with the module, to be a library. You don't have to publish it to use it. You can [use that library inside your application](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#using-your-own-library-in-applications).

Lastly, another solution is to have your projects completely separated. In that case, you can use `ng-paackagr` to extract the Angular module as a separate library. In that case, see [this tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-extract-an-angular-module-into-a-separate-library-with-ng-packagr) on how to do it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. could finally try it out. I would say: in theory it would work. The only problem is, that Angular Universal cannot be applied to a library. It throws "Universal requires a project type of 'application'.". That makes it more or less impossible, to separate Angular Universal and express into different projects